# Python- Coding so user can only select between 1 and 5 items

Tags: python

I'm coding a pizza ordering program as part of a school assessment. I've got the majority of the code down but **i need a way so that the user can enter up to 5 pizzas that they want from the menu and then the cost of the chosen pizzas to be stored for later**. So far I only have the menu of pizzas as I'm pretty lost.

The menu of pizzas that I have to use:

```
pizza_menu = {

   "Pepperoni": 8.50,

   "Cheese": 8.50,

   "Hawaiian": 8.50,

   "Meat Lovers": 8.50,

   "Margherita": 8.50,

   "Vegetarian" : 8.50,

   "Cheesy Garlic": 8.50,

   "Garlic Prawn": 13.50,

   "Mushroom Supreme": 13.50,

   "Italian Sausage": 13.50,

   "Meat Lovers Surpreme": 13.50,

   "Chicken Fajita": 13.50

}
```

Comment: Which part is a problem?

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried?

Comment: Try changing the message from `"Please enter up to 5 pizza flavours that you want: "` to `"Please enter up to 5 pizza flavours that you want (insert an empty line to finish): "`. Does this help?

Comment: You have a couple options. You could have them enter all of them on one line, and then split on commas, which seems like what you want to do. Check out the documentation for `str.split`, `str.strip`, and `str.lower`. I suggest trying to use these yourself, deleting this question, and writing a new question if you run into issues using them.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do it would be for the program to ask the question and the revert back to the 'menu' of options i.e: 1. Select another pizza, 2. checkout etc etc. each time a pizza is selected add that pizza to a list to keep track of the user orders.

ps: do you go to Scots College?

Comment: Thanks ill try this now, and nah I'm further up the country haha, did you get the same assessment?

Comment: Yea, same assessment a few years back, that's what most people used for the program. Create a menu of options and each time there is a an action by the user revert back to this menu of options so the user can carry out another action if desired

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways this can be done. The first option that might come to mind is to use a for loop that iterates the desired number of times:

```
pizza_choices = []
for _ in range(5):
    pizza_choice = input("Please enter up to 5 pizza flavours that you want: ")
    pizza_choices.append(pizza_choice)
```

Then sum the cost of the pizzas ordered using another for loop:

```
total = 0
for pizza_choice in pizza_choices:
    total += pizza_menu[pizza_choice]
print('Your total is:', total)
```

Another, perhaps more idiomatic option is to ask the user to enter each pizza separated by some delimiter, for example commas:

```
pizza_choices = input("Please enter up to 5 pizza flavours that you want (comma seperated): ")
pizza_choices = pizza_choices.split(',')
```

Then use the built-in function `sum` to get the total cost:

```
total = sum(pizza_menu[pizza_choice] for pizza_choice in pizza_choices)
```